# Smooth evolving histogram in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I'm porting some Mathematica [code](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/mathoverflow-gaussian-convergence.nb) and wondering if there's a way to do visualization like below in Python library like matplotlib or seaborne

[image]

Here's roughly equivalent [code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1t-BwH7biXFApGOmD9xPc0WVbLAlf_Rx8#scrollTo=wHsFoBaPtIuO) in matplotlib, but I'm stuck on figuring out how to do the shading properly

[image]

```
import numpy as np

def traj(p, d, B, alpha, num_steps):
    """Returns num_steps x B array of squared errors"""

    h = np.arange(1, d + 1)
    h = h ** -p
    hsqrt = np.sqrt(h)
    E = np.ones((B, d))
    traj = np.zeros((num_steps, B, d))

    for step_idx in range(num_steps):
        X = hsqrt * np.random.randn(B, d)
        losses = np.einsum("BD,BD->B", E, X)
        E -= alpha * np.einsum("BD,B->BD", X, losses)
        traj[step_idx] = E

    return np.sum(traj * traj, axis=2)

a = 2.421249521036836042
 
numQuantiles=7
errors = traj(p=0, d=1, B=3000, alpha=a, num_steps=100)
quantiles=np.zeros((numQuantiles, errors.shape[0]))
for q in range(numQuantiles):
    quantiles[q] = np.quantile(errors, (q+1)/(numQuantiles+1), axis=1)

quantiles = np.log(quantiles)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = list(range(1, 100+1))
plt.plot(x, quantiles[numQuantiles//2], marker='o')
plt.plot(x, quantiles[numQuantiles//2+1], marker='o')
plt.plot(x, quantiles[numQuantiles//2+2], marker='o')
plt.plot(x, quantiles[numQuantiles//2-1], marker='o')
plt.plot(x, quantiles[numQuantiles//2-2], marker='o')
```

Comment: `plt.fill_between(x, quantiles[numQuantiles//2-2], quantiles[numQuantiles//2+2], color='black', alpha=0.2)` etc.

Comment: This is the kind of thing Seaborn was built to do, and has much more thorough in-built support for multi-quantile plotting.